# Извлечь строку из фигурных скобок (Регулярное выражение PHP)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$data = "{0,1,?page=1,открыть}, {1,1,files/word.doc,скачать}";
```

Нужно получить массив из строк

```
"0,1,?page=1,открыть"
"1,1,files/word.doc,скачать"
```

Comment: Проще было хранить json и русские символы в base64. Этот недомассив ещё и был в одной колонке в базе. Не повторяйте моих ошибок)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = "{0,1,?page=1,открыть}, {1,1,files/word.doc,скачать}";
$arr=preg_split('/\{|\}(, *)?/',$data,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($arr);
```

Или

```
$data = "{0,1,?page=1,открыть}, {1,1,files/word.doc,скачать}";
preg_match_all('/\{.*?}/',$data,$arr);
var_dump($arr[0]);
```

В данном случае возвращается массив в 0 элементе которого лежит тот массив, который нужен.

Comment: Это какая-то магия. Благодарю, добрый человек :)